# System.debug() not displaying in debug logs

Tags: apex, trigger, debugging

I have a trigger called `DistancesToShow` that I see executing in a debug log. The trigger has a big if-then-else clause that can take it down many different paths. Based on the debug log, I can't quite tell which code path it's going down so I decided to add a bunch of debugging statements.

At the top of the trigger, right after some SOQL queries, I added the line:

```
System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Info,'>>>>>> inside DistancesToShow trigger');
```

I added several more `System.Debug()` messages at the top of each else clause to see which else I ended up in.

But no matter how many times I run it, I can't get it to display the message, even though it is definitely inside the trigger. I ran it a bunch of times trying to play with the different log levels, thinking I might not be understanding those. But at this point I'm logging everything and my simple debug messages aren't showing up.

I see that the trigger starts execution here:

```
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qi0000000Bn0P|DistancesToShow on Show trigger event AfterUpdate for [a023100000axfl7]
```

I then see three sets of `SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN` and `SOQL_EXECUTE_END`, each corresponding to an SOQL query I execute at the top of the trigger. Right below my last SOQL query is my `System.Debug()` message from above and it doesn't appear.

Why would my debug message not be appearing?

Comment: Debug will be visible in the logs, first you should share your code..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are few things that you need to check.

In your `debug level check in Apex code debug is set`
[image]

Second check your debug log size if its 2MB <= then SF skip the Debug statement in that case set all unwanted flag to none so that it will reduce your debug size and then you can see the debug. Also add a debug in start so that it give you confirmation that your debug is printed.

Comment: That did it! My debug log size was > 2MB. I didn't realize it was just skipping the debug statement in that case. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where do you see log size?

Comment: @NathanHinchey its on debug log page. You will find the debug size in bytes. You need to convert them.