# ActionFunction call a controller method but "system.debug" messages are not printed

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, actionfunction, debug-logs

I have a visualforce page with a page component showing a list of object.
I need to call a controller method when a user updates an `<apex:inputField>` in order to print in the log that value.

Visualforce page code:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="updConditions" action="{!updConditions}" immediate="true" rerender="none">
    <apex:param name="value" value=""/>
 </apex:actionFunction>

...

<apex:inputField value="{!value}" style="width:100%" type="number" id="value" onchange="updConditions(this.value)"/>
```

Controller method:

```
public void updConditions(){

        String x = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('value')
        System.debug('-------here: ' + x);
}
```

I am sure that the function `updConditions()` is executed, because I see the value of `x` using the developer console.

Why am I not able to print anything coming from a function called by an ActionFunction?

I already read [this developer forum discussion](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000IClmQAG)

Edit: My logging level

[image: logging level]

Comment: So you aren't seeing "--------here: " in the debug log either, right?  Can you say a little more about how you know the updConditions method is being executed?

Comment: I entered a breakpoint in the method so using the developer console I saw the value of 'x'.

Comment: Got it.  So we know it's running, but no part of your debug statement is being written out to the log, right?  What logging level do you have set for Apex code?  You can try forcing the debug statement to write out at that level. Example:  system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, '------- here: ' + x);

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld    I edit my question.

Comment: I have to admit I have seen this too recently wherein debug statements in getters were suppressed in some use cases leaving me baffled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:  [Summer'18 relaese note](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_debugging_log_limits.htm)

> We increased the size limit for debug logs from 2 MB per log to 5 MB.

If debug log size is bigger than 5MB SF skip the Debug statement. [stackexchange question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139902/system-debug-not-displaying-in-debug-logs?rq=1)

My debug log is bigger than 5MB.

In order to reduce debug log size, I change the APEX debug log level from FINEST to FINE.

Now I'm able to see my debug log.